# bootstrap and bootbox: set dialog box center of the screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I am using bootbox.js from http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html and it is quite impressive. But I have an issue while setting up the location of the dialog box.

I want to place dialog box center of the screen. I am using this code but dialog box stays on top of the screen.

```
 bootbox.alert('Danger!!').find('.modal-content').css({
     'background-color': '#f99',
     'font-weight': 'bold',
     color: '#F00',
     'top': '50%',
     'margin-top': function() {
         return -(box.height() / 2);
     },
     'font-size': '2em',
     'font-weight': 'bold'
 });
```

Please advise how can set the dialog box center of the screen.

Comment: Does other CSS attributes worked in the above example?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of **Bootbox** 5, you can actually enable this via an option, [centerVertical](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-option-centerVertical):

```js
bootbox.alert({
    message: "I'm a vertically-centered dialog!",
    centerVertical: true
});
```

Comment: Bootstrap 5 is not necessary - it requires Bootstrap 4.1.0 according to the link.

Comment: @anotherfred Read the answer a bit more carefully - I specifically said Bootbox, not Bootstrap.

Answer (score 16):

If you want a vertical centered bootbox modal via css3

```
.modal-open .modal {
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

You can have more flexibility here: 
https://www.kirupa.com/html5/centering_vertically_horizontally.htm
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 13):

Modal is already centered in horizontal direction. If you want vertical centered modal, hope this will work for you

```
bootbox.alert('Danger!!' ).find('.modal-content').css({
    'background-color': '#f99',
    'font-weight' : 'bold',
    'color': '#F00',
    'font-size': '2em',
    'margin-top': function (){
        var w = $( window ).height();
        var b = $(".modal-dialog").height();
        // should not be (w-h)/2
        var h = (w-b)/2;
        return h+"px";
    }
});
```

Giving this answer according to your example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.

Comment: Works well but for me var b was returning zero, I changed to: var b = $(this).height(); // $(".modal-dialog").height();

Answer (score 4):

This question is quite old, but another short option would be to use the corresponding bootstrap class:

`bootbox.alert('Danger!!')
  .find(".modal-dialog")
  .addClass("modal-dialog-centered");`

This works with Bootstrap **v4.0.0** or higher.